# First Time On List item Click Text Color not Changes

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, onitemclick

I have a custom list view in fragment , and on Item Click text color changes and marquee running, but on first time item click none of things is working , no marquee or no text color changes, and on second time click both working fine. Please Help!!

```
mainListViews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                song_namef.setText(text);

                setItemNormal();
                View rowView = view;
                views=rowView;
                setItemSelected(rowView);
            }});

public void setItemSelected(View view){
    View rowView = view;

    TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    tv.setSelected(true);
    tv.requestFocus();
}

public void setItemNormal()
{
    for (int i=0; i< mainListViews.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mainListViews.getChildAt(i);
        TextView txtview = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView));
        txtview.setSelected(false);
        txtview.setSingleLine(true);
        txtview.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor));
    }}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
app:cardElevation="16dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
android:divider="#B49238"
>
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView19" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView16">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dip"
        android:textColor="@color/tabsScrollColor"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:src="@drawable/musicalbum"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dip"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** to your row item 
It should work fine
Let me know if you still getting issue

Comment: its not working !! i try to apply this on my  textview !!

Comment: don't apply on textview
you should apply root view

Comment: i try in root view i.e my card view !! but no luck :(

Comment: is posted xml layout is your row layout in listview?

Comment: yes . Above this root Linear Layout i am using cardview and image!!